Is it possible to create Viber deep link that opens Viber app and send message to a group or channel?
Is it possible to create viber deep link that will send a message to multiple participatns (by specifying their phone numbers) or to the viber group?
I managed to get only a viber one to one deep link.
I don't need automated message, but rather a button in my web app when clicked to open viber app on my phone
